# Upload buffer sizes when transferring files over LAN/internet?

Tags: c#, network-programming, buffer

When reading a local file and sending it across a network (local as well as internet), is there any suggested or recommended buffer size? We're using 4k since it's the Windows VM page size but since this can be a complex function of latency, bandwidth, jitter etc, I would like to understand an implementation that can do well in most cases. We would prefer a simpler solution to minimize lines of code changes (code audit).

```
using (var destFs = new NetworkStream(URI, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    var buffer = new byte[4*1024]; // <= better buffer size?
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        destFs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Comment: 4096 is most often what I see, but I can't prove it with science.

Comment: In my career I have experienced that the best value is 8192, but I don't know. But it seems faster.

Answer (score 0):

it depends !

> If you are using TCP (You may be intrested here )

The absolute limitation on TCP packet size is 64K (65535 bytes), but in practicality this is far larger than the size of any packet you will see, because the lower layers (e.g. ethernet) have lower packet sizes.

The MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) for Ethernet, for instance, is 1500 bytes. Some types of networks (like Token Ring) have larger MTUs, and some types have smaller MTUs, but the values are fixed for each physical technology.

> If you are using UDP

The correct maximum UDP message size is 65507, as determined by the following formula: 0xffff - (sizeof(IP Header) + sizeof(UDP Header)) = 65535-(20+8) = 65507

Comment: The maximum TCP packet size, MTUs etc., are all irrelevant to how large an application buffer can be, as TCP does the packetising.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it a power of 2, and you should also make it a multiple of 4096 for the reason you give, also that it is a common disk cluster size. Personally I use 8192 everywhere, but if you're interested in throughput you may well find it better to use sizes like 32k, 128k, etc: experiment will show where the benefits start becoming marginal.

Comment: Weird downvoter since the answer makes sense though it's not 'rock solid'. Given the number of underlying network variables, it's hard for a one line C# statement to be `rock solid`. Anyway, I voted it up ...

Comment: I agree with 8192. In my testing is the best value.